# NInject2 Interceptor usage with NHibernate transactions

Tags: .net, nhibernate, transactions, ninject, interceptor

In my previous project we used NHibernate and Spring.NET.

Transactions were handled by adding [Transaction] attribute to service methods.

In my current project I'm using NHibernate and NInject 2 and I was wondering if it's possible to solve transaction handling using "Ninject.Extensions.Interception" and similar [Transaction] type attributes?

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this project solves my problem

http://github.com/chillitom/ninject.extensions.spring.tx